# while using SVG in mask property , the SVG doesn't appear

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, sass

I'm using Reactjs and SCSS , this is the code =>

```
background-color: $color-primary;
-webkit-mask-image: url("./assets/images/SVG/chevron-thin-right.svg");
-webkit-mask-size: cover;
```

configuration =>

```
{
            test: /\.svg$/,
            loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
            options: {
                extract: false,
                runtimeCompat: true,
                esModule: false
            }
        },
```

Comment: 1. Is your mask image showing a black grafic? Masks only leave visible what is white (or at least non-black). Transparent areas are considered black. 2. According to [canniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks), Chrome/Safari may not support the `mask-size` property.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Ccprog for reply . I work on a course project , lecturer doesn't use reactjs within the course and he didn't face issues like this with SVG's . when he put the URL that refer to the SVG in mask property it done well , when i'm trying to applies it i face the previous problem .